# Is there more efficient way to index an array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have no idea what keyword should I use on google to find the solution.

This is my code:

```
function getArray(){
 return array('one','two','three');
}

$array = getArray();
echo $array[2];
```

My question is there a more efficient way to print the third element from the returned array?

Comment: Array dereferencing: `echo getArray()[2];` is about as efficient as it gets.... requires PHP >= 5.4.0

Comment: The only alternativeswould be `echo end ($array)` or `echo array_pop($array)`, but that's not really more efficient.

Comment: As it's the last element you could also use `echo end(getArray());`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the easiest way to print the x-th element of the array, you should use a parameter in your function.

This way you can also do some checks to see if the index is valid.

```
function getArray($index){
  $array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  if ($index < 0 || $index >= count($array)) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return $array[$index];
  }
}

echo getArray(2);
```

Comment: The `$index < 0 || $index >= count($array)` can be simplified to `!array_key_exists($index, $array)`.

Comment: Surely adding another function overhead makes it *less* efficient overall?